# Two dimensional array filled like target algorithm. Distance from center

Tags: arrays, algorithm, multidimensional-array

I have two dimensional , always square array, but I **do not know the length ** of both dimensions . However I have to fill it out like a target. Take look at picture:
[image: array filled like aim]

I have tried to extract functions like `Math.abs( min(i,j) - N )` or I have even tried to use our mathematical algebra to mesure distance between points - but it was useless. I assumed that the N value is `N = (board.length/2) + 1;` but it is not a rule.

Comment: What is your question? I don't understand

Comment: I need to fill array with values like on picture. Thanks.

Comment: Does the initial square is always in center?

Comment: Yes, it is. And dimentions are allways odd.

Comment: Your formula is fine but if a single square must be the center then a requirement is that both width and height are odd.

Comment: Just little confusing on the undefined `n`. Is it a variable that gets passed before creating the "target"? Ultimately, how is it defined? If `border.length` is of type `int` and defines the width of the board, the `N = (board.length/2) + a;` would always work (if you expect the border to have a value of `a`)

Comment: Yes, board is int typed. N is not so important. I just want to have lesser value the further the cell is from center.

Answer (score 3):

You probably want something like:

```
N - max(Math.abs(x-i), Math.abs(y-j))
```

where `(i,j)` is your target location, and `(x,y)` are your array indices.

Comment: Sorry, but this function is wrong. After implementation, first row looks like 1 2 3 4 3 2 1 but it should be filled with only onces. **I got expected result with changing min to max function.**

Comment: You want `max`, not `min`, I believe.

Comment: Thanks, I have fixed my answer accordingly.